# How can I display top upregulated and downregulated genes on a volcano plot (ex. top 10)?

Tags: r

I want to display the gene labels of the significant genes on my VP, how can I set a threshold to say display the top x genes upregulated and downregulated in my data set.

Thanks so much!

Data code

```
Pro_FvsM <- data.frame(log2FC = FprovM_df$log.foldchange_F_pro.M,
                  logpv = -log10(FprovM_df$pvalue))

Pro_FvsM$diffexpressed <- "NON-Significant"

Pro_FvsM$diffexpressed[Pro_FvsM$log2FC > 0.8] <- "UP"

Pro_FvsM$diffexpressed[Pro_FvsM$log2FC < -0.8] <- "DOWN"

GeneList <- FprovM_df$Genes

Pro_FvsM_2 <- cbind(Pro_FvsM, GeneList)

Pro_FvsM_2$genelabels <- ""
```

Plot code

```
ggplot(Pro_FvsM_2) + geom_point(aes(log2FC, logpv, col = diffexpressed)) + geom_text_repel(aes(log2FC, logpv), label = ifelse(Pro_FvsM_2$GeneList == TRUE, as.character(Pro_FvsM_2$GeneList), ""), box.padding = unit(0.75, "lines"), hjust = 0.35) + theme(legend.title = element_blank(), text = element_text(size = 15)) + scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subset the data and then plot. You didn't provide a reproducible example, so I am downloading some similar gene data from here and then reading it in as `df`.

```
download.file("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/biocorecrg/CRG_RIntroduction/master/de_df_for_volcano.rds", "de_df_for_volcano.rds", method="curl")
```

Code:

```
df$diffexpressed[df$log2FoldChange > 0.8] <- "UP"
df$diffexpressed[df$log2FoldChange < -0.8] <- "DOWN"

# create subset of data meeting whatever criteria to use to label

dfLabel <- df[df$diffexpressed %in% c("UP", "DOWN"),]
```

Plot:

```
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_point(aes(log2FoldChange, pvalue, col = diffexpressed)) +
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(aes(log2FoldChange, pvalue, label = gene_symbol), 
                            data = dfLabel)  # specify `dfLabel` data
```

[image]